# Is it possible to conditionally require a property in a Typescript interface

Tags: typescript

Say I have the following interface:

```
interface updateOptions {
  updateAll: boolean;
  fields: string[];
}
```

Is there a way to make `updateAll` required when `Fields` is not provided and vice versa, or is this something that must be done conditionally in the implementation?

Comment: do you mean `type updateOptions = { updateAll: boolean } | { fields: string[] }` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use tagged union type:

```
type UpdateOptions =
  | {updateAll: true}
  | {updateAll: false, fields: string[]}
```

This way you can only initialize `{updateAll: true}` or `{updateAll: false, fields: ['someField', /*...*/]}`

Technically, the union doesn't need to have a tag (the boolean `updateAll`), but then you need to define type guard to test which type is being used in a particular branch (I assume somewhere in your code you will do `if (options.updateAll) {/* ... */}`):

```
type UpdateAllOptions = {updateAll: true}
type UpdateSomeOptions = {fields: string[]}
type UpdateOptions = UpdateAllOptions | UpdateSomeOptions

// See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards
const isAllOptions = (options: UpdateOptions): options is UpdateAllOptions =>
  (options as any).updateAll === true
```